# Capturing all output from Bitbake build / Using Coverity with Bitbake

Tags: bitbake

It seems Bitbake build creates processes that print the actual build outputs to log files rather than standard output.

Is there a way to make them print to stdout? I need this to analyze a software with Coverity. Coverity captures the calls to the compiler from stdout to figure out which files to analyze and with what options they are built. With Bitbake it can't see a single compile command...

Comment: Coverity is a company, not a product.  [Which of their products](http://coverity.com/products/) are you using?

Comment: Static analysis. Do you actually build the sw with any of their other tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coverity Static Analysis does not depend on anything being output to "standard output" to work.  The issue you are seeing with BitBake is caused by environment variables that SA relies on to capture calls to the compiler being wiped clean by BitBake.

In order to resolve the problem you need to white list variables SA uses with BitBake (likely by setting `BB_ENV_WHITELIST` or equivalent appropriately).

I think BitBake may have a way to preserve the entire environment (setting `BB_PRESERVE_ENV`) however, I don't know if that may impact your native build so I would hesitate to suggest it.

Comment: Yeah, I got this solved in the end but forgot to mention it here. I edited the whitelist in the bitbake utils.py file by adding a bunch of variables there.